# Stream cutting in java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

What is a good method to cut  stream?
I have just started java 8 and I am stuck at this.
I am reading from a file a couple of input date and then printing them. My problems is how do I cut precisely between the dates and the string ?
can "tab" be used?
What I have so far:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {

            Supplier<Stream<String>> fisier=()->{
                    try {
                        return Files.lines(Paths.get("Activities.txt"));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                };
                fisier.get().forEach(System.out::println);
                //fisier.get().filter(predicate)
                //List<String>out=getFilterOutput(fisier.get(),"    ");
    }
```

I have thought about filtering the information, but how can I tell for what to look >?
A line from the file looks like this:

> 2011-12-11 15:43:51       2011-12-11 21:41:48     Spare_Time/TV

Comment: what is the definition of "cut" in your understanding? so let's take that example of yours `2011-12-11 15:43:51 2011-12-11 21:41:48 Spare_Time/TV`... after the so-called "cut" what would the result be?

Comment: a variable gets 2012-12-11 15:43:51 ,another gets 2012-12-11 21-41-48 and another one gets spare_time/tv

Comment: so you basically want to *split* your String, not cut

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
    List <String> firstDate = new ArrayList<>();
    List <String> secondDate = new ArrayList<>();
    List <String> showName = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

        stream.forEach(line -> {
            String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
            firstDate.add(parts[0] + parts[1]);
            secondDate.add(parts[2] + parts[3]);
            showName.add(parts[4]);
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is this like the split function from Strings?I used it a while back. Does "\\" mean to retain what is before? What is with the s or the +?

Comment: It is a `greedy regular expression`. It will eat any number of whitespaces.

Comment: @Maria that is a `regex` -> `\\s+` means split, where the separator is any number of whitespaces

Comment: That is the issue, there is a white space between date and time and more than just one white space between the two dates.

Comment: @Maria have you actually tried this code? that pattern will take care of that, that `+` means one or more whitespaces...

Comment: What is the issue? This will split at any space sequence it encounters. Afterwards you can join/append what you need.

Comment: @NiVeR you should probably also start explaining why `flatMap` is going to be needed here...

Comment: @Eugene Hmm, why would they need `flatMap` here? It seems that the file has a static structure.

Comment: @NiVeR `lineOfFile.split("\\s+")` will return an array, basically giving you a `Stream<String[]>` and you want a `Stream<String>`

Comment: @NiVeR I dont think you understood my point or at least Im not sure you did. How about u create a small example and run it?

Comment: @NiVeR loaded the file into stream? You need a lot more than just trying an example judging by this sentence...

Comment: I have tried it. It keeps returning memory adresses such as [Ljava.lang.String;@16ec8df

Comment: @Eugene Can you explain what is wrong with the updated code?

Comment: @NiVeR well *at least* use `forEachOrdered`; add `parallel` to your stream and see the result. Besides, where have you seen the OP collecting those parts to different lists anyway?

Comment: @Eugene `a variable gets 2012-12-11 15:43:51 ,another gets 2012-12-11 21-41-48 and another one gets spare_time/tv`. It is a comment on your comment.

Comment: @Eugene Regarding ordering, I don't see any requirement that the file should be processeed according some order.

Comment: @NiVeR the point is not about order per-se, you are violating the side-effects here - that is the point.

Comment: @Eugene I get what you mean, there will be a problem in case of parallel stream.